# HTTP to HTTPS redirect issue with iis8.5 and Websphere7

Tags: iis, websphere-7, url-rewrite-module, iis-8.5, isapi-rewrite

We have applications hosted on WebSphere 7.0 and Jboss EAP7 which is behind IIS 8.5 Web server, we enabled ssl for iis.

our requirement is whenever users access with http it has to be redirected to https, to achieve this we configured rewrite2 module in iis below inbound rule

```
<rules>
    <rule name="http to https" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
    </rule>
```

issue :- when i access http://www.example.com/login  it redirects to https://www.example.com/sePlugins/iisWASPlugin_http.dll and gives 404 Status code. (only applications hosted websphere)
    The problem is that we have a ISAPI Websphere plugin to handle the requests and for some reason URL is getting changed by IIS.

redirect rule works fine for Applications hosted on J BOSS.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened to my registration process but I posted the original answer so reposting again after registering.

I found that specifying `{CACHE_URL}` in the Redirect Url instead of `https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}` worked. so `url="{CACHE_URL}"`

This is how my rule is defined and it seems to work well.

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{CACHE_URL}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found that specifying `{CACHE_URL}` in the Redirect Url instead of `https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}` worked.  so `url="{CACHE_URL}"`

Comment: Please share more details

Comment: Please delete this answer. Next time, try to edit your answer instead of creating a new one. Learn how to use Stack Overflow and follow the basic rules.